# Как оптимизировать запрос с выборкой по кол-ву встречаемых значений к postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Необходимо выбрать максимум 10 категорий, которые будут содержать минимум 3 сообщения от разных пользователей, при этом данные сообщения должны быть последними среди всех сообщений.
Результат должен быть такой:
Название категории | Сообщение | Имя автора | Дата

я сделал вот такой запрос:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (category_id) categories.name, text, users.name, posted_at 
FROM messages 
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = messages.category_id
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = messages.author_id
WHERE category_id IN ( SELECT msg.category_id 
                       FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (category_id, author_id) category_id 
                              FROM messages 
                              ORDER BY category_id, author_id, posted_at
                            ) AS msg 
                       GROUP BY (msg.category_id) 
                       HAVING COUNT(*) > 2 
                       LIMIT 10 
                     ) 
ORDER BY category_id, posted_at DESC
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mQWMqDfa8wq4WSSyHuf38e/3)

Но он выполняется около 15 секунд на 10 млн записях.

Comment: Избавляйтесь от WHERE IN, переписывайте на честный JOIN (в крайнем случае на коррелированный WHERE EXISTS). PS. LIMIT без ORDER BY - это лотерея.

Comment: *Необходимо выбрать максимум 10 категорий, которые будут содержать минимум 3 сообщения от разных пользователей, при этом данные сообщения должны быть последними среди всех сообщений* Надо ли это понимать так: "сначала отбросить все категории, имеющие менее 3 сообщений, из оставшихся выбрать 10 случайных, для каждой выбранной вывести последние 3 сообщения"?

Comment: Сначала надо выбрать все категории, которые имеют не менее 3 сообщений от разных людей, отсортировать категории по последнему сообщению (DESC). Вывести необходимо 10 первых категорий по предыдущему сорту, формат вывода:  Название категории | Сообщение | Имя автора | Дата сообщения

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT c.name
          FROM messages m
          INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = m.category_id
          INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = m.author_id 
          GROUP BY c.name
          HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) >= 3
        ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                 c.name, 
                 FIRST_VALUE(m.text) OVER (PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY m.posted_at DESC) "text", 
                 FIRST_VALUE(u.name) OVER (PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY m.posted_at DESC) "name", 
                 MAX(m.posted_at) OVER (PARTITION BY c.name) posted_at
          FROM messages m
          INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = m.category_id
          INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = m.author_id
          INNER JOIN cte1 ON c.name = cte1.name
        )
SELECT * 
FROM cte2;
```

или, если избавиться от CTE, которые материализуются в постгрессе

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       c.name, 
       FIRST_VALUE(m.text) OVER (PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY m.posted_at DESC) "text", 
       FIRST_VALUE(u.name) OVER (PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY m.posted_at DESC) "name", 
       MAX(m.posted_at) OVER (PARTITION BY c.name) posted_at
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = m.category_id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = m.author_id
INNER JOIN ( SELECT c.name
             FROM messages m
             INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = m.category_id
             INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = m.author_id 
             GROUP BY c.name
             HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) >= 3
           ) cte1 ON c.name = cte1.name
```

Comment: то решение, которое я выложил выполнилось за 25 сек, затем я запустил ваше, но на 5 минуте мне пришлось отменить запрос, т.к. он еще не завершился.
Нахожусь в поисках ответа на свой вопрос. Пока есть возможный вариант оптимизации, но я не знаю возможно ли это. в моем фиддле на 21 строке есть "GROUP BY (msg.category_id) HAVING COUNT(*) > 2", возможно ли после удаления групп, которые не подходят по HAVING условию, разгруппировать?

Comment: @Kojan На реальном наборе данных и на модели результаты будут, конечно, разными - но вот именно на модели fiddle устойчиво показывает выигрыш по execution time почти в полтора раза для запроса без CTE. Посмотрите, что будет на вашем десятимиллионном наборе данных. *возможно ли после удаления групп, которые не подходят по HAVING условию, разгруппировать?* Нет, конечно. Только join к ещё одной копии таблицы.

Comment: на фиддле мой выполняется за ~270, ваш 1 вариант за ~590, второй за ~510. Возможно посоветуете настройки postgres?)
В реальности понятно, что можно добавить триггер и кэшировать данные, но что насчет того, чтобы как-то увеличить скорость работы запроса?

Comment: *на фиддле мой выполняется за ~270, ваш 1 вариант за ~590, второй за ~510.* Запустил десяток раз, для каждого из трёх запросов Execution time пляшет от 2 до 10 ms. Так что на таких данных ничего не увидеть. Нужны данные по времени на реальном массиве. PS. А вот на db-fiddle.uk при выводе explain время моего запроса на модельных данных стабильно в полтора раза меньше.

Comment: Вы можете подсказать по конфигурации бд? Мб что-нибудь в конфиге изменить?